# Difference between Vacuous and Empty

Tags: synonyms

I thought that **Empty** was the word, that besides its original meaning, could be used when you refer to some abstract idea, like "I feel like my soul is empty today". However, recently I've encountered the word **Vacuous** in the same abstract contaxt "That idea is vacuous".

So what's the difference between those two?

Comment: Have you checked the meanings in a dictionary?

Comment: Sure, I have, in several dictionaries.

Comment: The use of *vacuous* to mean "empty" is archaic. The other meaning given by [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=vacuous+meaning) is current.

Comment: You can't be serious if you refer to Google for finding the English translations / vocabulary.. So, before asking whether "have I checked the dictionary?" please consider what is your sources of English, rather than being rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real difference is that empty is used more in the context of objects and vacuous has evolved into a modern slander for calling somebody empty minded.

> I tried to explain but the woman was vacuous.

But there is still nothing wrong with, and may even be slightly more polite to say

> I tried to explain but the woman was empty minded.

I would say it is borderline rude to use vacuous, verging on arrogant. So avoid where you can, unless you are looking to insult with an erudite manner.

**Edit**

You can also use the term to describe an expression.

> She had a vacuous expression ever since her cat died three weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks for answer, that's pretty much what I wrote, right? Vacuous is something that I met in abstract, indirect context.

Comment: Empty-*headed* would be the more idiomatic rendering of *vacuous,* and we often speak of a facial expression suggestive of either mental vacuity or flat affect as a *vacuous expression.* Finally, *empty* is quite applicable to OP's *soul* or *life* to indicate a spiritual emptiness, as distinct from the lack of intellectual faculties that is usually meant by *vacuous.*

Comment: Calling someone *vacuous* is certainly not a slander. That's a ridiculous idea. Calling an argument *vacuous* (having or showing a lack of thought or intelligence) is reasonable enough.

Comment: Mick you are vacuous.

Comment: I think my friends share your opinion (but they are too polite to tell me). :-]

Comment: You are correct though, it can be used to describe a blank expression without any indication of how empty the mind is. Like a lack of emotion. I think we link the two a little too much in other language and social mannerisms. Reading a book by its cover. I will amend my answer.